# Could not activate JNI Handle of Java type 'MvxAppCompatRadioGroup'

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, androidx

I have this error:

### Could not activate JNI Handle of Java type 'mvvmcross/platforms/android/binding/views/MvxAppCompatRadioGroup' as managed type 'MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Binding.Views.MvxAppCompatRadioGroup'.

when inflate custom layout with MvxAppCompatRadioGroup.
I change my element class for AndroidX migration, how can I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `MvxAppCompatRadioGroup` does still exist. You find it here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Platforms/Android/Binding/Views/MvxAppCompatRadioGroup.cs

Does this error always happen or only sometimes?

Comment: Yes, but the error occurs every time that I try to create this layout.

Comment: And does it only happen in Release builds or also Debug builds? What are your Linker settings?